# Why is "shutdown p 01:00" not working?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, time

[image]

Comment: Try `shutdown --help` for more information.

Comment: You can mark multiple lines of code in the shell with the mouse easily. To paste the marked lines you just have to click the middle-button in the target place. That's much more easy than producing, sending, and lastly reading a graphical screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `-P`, not `-p`. It's case sensitive. Also realize that you'll have to be root to shutdown like that.

For the time, there are different ways to enter. Taken from `man shutdown`:

```
       TIME  may  have  different  formats, the most common is simply the word
   'now' which will bring the system down immediately.  Other  valid  for‐
   mats  are  +m,  where m is the number of minutes to wait until shutting
   down and hh:mm which specifies the time on the 24hr clock.
```

Example:

```
$ sudo shutdown -P 20:30
[sudo] password for ward: 

Broadcast message from ward@sekhmet
(/dev/pts/0) at 20:14 ...

The system is going down for power off in 16 minutes!
```